# Adding back and next buttons ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

I am trying to add back and next buttons to the Wifi Manager activity.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS

In previous requests using the following extra was suggested

```
Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
intent.putExtra("extra_prefs_show_button_bar", true);
getActivity().startActivityFromFragment(this,intent, 0);
```

but I don't think this is supported in the latest android APIs.

Is any way around this? Can I wrap the WifiManager in a custom layout and add the buttons myself?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am trying to add back and next buttons to the Wifi Manager activity.

You are welcome to download the Android open source code, alter the Settings app as you see fit, compile the results into a ROM mod, and convince people to run that ROM mod.

> Can I wrap the WifiManager in a custom layout and add the buttons myself?

No. The Settings app is another app, not your app.